# SQL Error: Procedure or function 'CreateUserAccount' expects parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, exception, ado.net

I have debugged the code and from what I see I do have my parameters added with the value, but can anyone help in solving this? I don't think I can see any problem, but I another pair of eyes may help.

Method

```
    public bool CreateUserAccount(string firstName, string lastName, string aboutUser, string email, string password, 
        string addressLine1, string addressLine2, string city, string postcode, string contactNumber)
    {
        bool registered = false;
        try
        {
            connection = OpenSqlConnection();

            command = new SqlCommand(CREATE_USER_ACCOUNT, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(FIRST_NAME, firstName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(LAST_NAME, lastName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ABOUT_USER, aboutUser);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(USER_EMAIL, email);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(USER_PASSWORD, password);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ADDRESS_LINE_1, addressLine1);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ADDRESS_LINE_2, addressLine2);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CITY, city);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(POSTCODE, postcode);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CONTACT_NUMBER, contactNumber);

            registered = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return registered;
    }
```

SQL

```
ALTER PROC CreateUserAccount
(
@FirstName VARCHAR(50),
@LastName VARCHAR(50),
@AboutUser VARCHAR(3000),
@UserEmail VARCHAR(200),
@UserPassword VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50),
@City VARCHAR(50),
@Postcode VARCHAR(50),
@ContactNumber VARCHAR(50)
)
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @Registered INT
IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE usr_Email = @UserEmail))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [User]
    VALUES
        (
            NEWID(),
            @FirstName,
            @LastName,
            @AboutUser,
            @UserEmail,
            @UserPassword,
            @AddressLine1,
            @AddressLine2,
            @City,
            @Postcode,
            @ContactNumber
        )
    SET @Registered = 1
    PRINT 'Implemented' -- for testing purposes
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Registered = 0
    PRINT 'Not implemented' -- for testing purposes
END
RETURN @Registered
END
```

Comment: Without reading your code I'm going to guess you forgot to specify CommandType in SqlCommand

Comment: Having read your code, I'm going to surmise that I'm correct

Comment: Also, we have no idea what your constant `FIRST_NAME` is set to.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (note CommandType)

```
public bool CreateUserAccount(string firstName, string lastName, string aboutUser, string email, string password, 
    string addressLine1, string addressLine2, string city, string postcode, string contactNumber)
{
    bool registered = false;
    try
    {
        connection = OpenSqlConnection();

        command = new SqlCommand(CREATE_USER_ACCOUNT, connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(FIRST_NAME, firstName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(LAST_NAME, lastName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ABOUT_USER, aboutUser);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(USER_EMAIL, email);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(USER_PASSWORD, password);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ADDRESS_LINE_1, addressLine1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ADDRESS_LINE_2, addressLine2);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CITY, city);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(POSTCODE, postcode);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(CONTACT_NUMBER, contactNumber);

        registered = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return registered;
}
```

Also, ensure that your `FIRST_NAME` variable/constant is set to `FirstName` or `@FirstName`

Comment: yes thank you, i was missing the command type, dont know how i missed that... my constants are right. Thanks again.

Comment: It's easily done :) I used to do it a lot but have got wise to the error of my ways!

Comment: yeah :) maybe because im up at 1am in london programming..half asleep